# Ler uma parte do conteúdo do arquivo

Tags: php

Possuo um arquivo .txt grande que está basicamente assim:

```
1000#
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt.#

1001#
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt.#
```

Estou querendo que seja lido apenas o respectivo ID pedido, mas que seja lido apenas o texto entre as tags.

Exemplo, quero buscar o valor do texto `1001`. Ai seria retornado dessa maneira:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt.
```

Aqui está o código que para tentar implementar:

```
$file = "id.txt";
$f = fopen($file, 'rb');
$found = false;
while ($line = fgets($f, 1000)) {
    if ($found) {
       echo $line;
       continue;
    }
    if (strpos($line, "1000") !== FALSE) {
      $found = true;
    }
}
```

Com ele consigo alcançar o valor do ID, porém lê tudo dessa direção para baixo! !ueria que parasse no final da #, ou seja, ler o texto entre o #TEXTO#.

Comment: Adicione na sua pergunta as tentativas que você já fez.

Comment: Desculpe a minha pergunta, eu esqueci totalmente das minhas tentativas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Existem diversos meios como:

#### Com expressões regulares:

Buscar um único registro

```
$data = '1000#
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt.#

1001#
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt.#';

function buscarTexto($id, $data) {
    $re = '/(?<=^'.$id.'#\r?\n).+?(?=#$)/sm';

    return preg_match($re, $data, $match) ? $match[0] : null;
}
```

Breve explicação da expressão regular

```regex
/
(?<=^ #Casa a linha do id registro sem capturá-la
    $id #id do registro
#\n)
.+? #Casa o texto e o captura
(?=#$) #Casa o delimitador final do texto sem capturá-lo
/smx
#o flag s faz com que o ponto capture as quebras de linhas
#o flag m faz com que os operadores ^ e $ casem o inicio e final das linhas
#o flag x não foi utilizado no código mas faz com que o espaços presentes na expressão não sejam considerados.
```

Carregar todos os registros em um array em que a chave é o id.

```
function buscarTextos($data) {
    $re = '/(?<id>^\d+)(?:#\r?\n)(?<text>.+?)(?:#$)/sm';
    $result = [];

    if(preg_match_all($re, $data, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER))
        //Converte o resultado da expressão em um array id => texto
        foreach($matches as $m) 
            $result[$m['id']] = $m['text'];

    return $result;
}
```

Breve explicação da expressão regular

```regex
/
(?<id>^\d+) #Armazena id do registro em um grupo separado
(?:#\n) #Casa o delimitador do id e a quebra de linha
(?<texto>.+?) #Armazena o texto em outro grupo
(?:#$) #Casa o delimitador final do texto
/gsmx
#o flag g faz com que sejam capturadas todos os registros
#o flag s faz com que o ponto capture as quebras de linhas
#o flag m faz com que os operadores ^ e $ casem o inicio e final das linhas
#o flag x não foi utilizado no código mas faz com que o espaços presentes na expressão não sejam considerados.
```

#### Sem expressões regulares

Ler linha a linha e retornar o registro desejado

```
function buscarTexto2($id, $data) {
    $rows = explode("\n", $data);
    $id = $id.'#';
    $text = '';
    $found = false;

    foreach($rows as $r) {
        //Remove possíveis espaços em branco
        $r = trim($r);

        //Verifica se a linha corresponde ao id do registro selecionado
        if($r === $id) 
            $found = true;
        //Caso tenha encontrado o registro
        elseif($found) {
            //Aqui é assumido que o texto pode ter diversas linhas
            $text .= $text == '' ? $r : PHP_EOL.$r;

            //Então caso a linha lida termine com $
            if(substr($text, -1, 1) == '#')
                //Retorna o texto
                return substr($text, 0, -1);
        }
    }
}
```

Ler linha a linha e armazenar todos os registros em um array em que a chave é o id.

```
function buscarTextos2($data) {
    $rows = explode("\n", $data);
    $id = null;
    $text = '';
    $result = [];

    foreach($rows as $r) {
        //Remove possíveis espaços em branco
        $r = trim($r);

        //verifica se algum registro está sendo processado no momento
        if($id === null) {

            //Ignora linhas em branco caso nenhum registro esteja sendo processado no momento.
            if(!$r)
                continue;

            //Armazena o id e desconsidera o último caractere que é o $
            $id = substr($r, 0, -1);
        } else {
            //Aqui é assumido que o texto pode ter diversas linhas
            $text .= $text == '' ? $r : PHP_EOL.$r;

            //Então caso a linha lida termine com $
            if(substr($text, -1, 1) == '#') {
                //Adiciona o registro ao array
                $result[$id] = substr($text, 0, -1);

                //E se prepara para o processamento de um novo registro
                $id = null;
                $text = '';
            }
        }
    }

    return $result;
}
```

Em todas as funções foi assumido que o #(hashtag) é o último caractere da linha.

Você pode testar o código no seguinte link http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/y1kq-jg7w

Caso queira utilizá-las com o conteúdo de arquivo faça o seguinte:

```
$dados = file_get_contents('caminho do arquivo');

$texto = buscarTexto(1000, $dados);
//ou
$texto = buscarTexto2(1000, $dados);
//ou
$textos = buscarTextos($dados);
//ou
$textos = buscarTextos2($dados);
```

Comment: Olá Hwapx, obrigado pela colaboração. Eu acho que não fui muito claro na minha pergunta. Eu percebi que usando o caractere $(dolar) pode dar coflito, pois pode ser interpretado pelo comando por outra maneira. Preferi alterar de $ para # ficando assim:
1000#
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt.#

1001#
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt.#

Eu esqueci de mencionar tambem que esse texto está dentro de um arquivo .txt. E estou procurando um meio de tentar ler apenas o texto  sem o ID

Comment: Alterei as funções para utilizarem #, as funções buscarTexto e buscarTexto2 retornam somente o texto do registro, no link http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/y1kq-jg7w você pode testá-las e ver seu resultado, fiz elas para receberem o texto diretamente o qual você pode obter do arquivo com `$conteudo = file_get_contents('caminho do arquivo')`.

Comment: Aqui não há nenhuma linha com essa codigo $conteudo = file_get_contents('caminho do arquivo'), poderia reenviar novamente?

Comment: Adicionei um exemplo da leitura do arquivo na resposta.

Comment: Ainda não esta sendo lido, não aparece nada. Vale lembrar que é para ler entre os dois #.

1001#TEXTO AQUI#
1002#TEXTOAQUI 2#

Quando eu buscar o id 1001 sair apenas o TEXTO AQUI

Comment: Você ajustou o caminho do arquivo? baseado na sua pergunta deveria ficar como `$file = 'id.txt';
$dados = file_get_contents($file);` tente ver se o arquivo está sendo lido colocando um `var_dump($dados);` na linha seguinte ao `file_get_contents`.

Comment: Quando adiciono var_dump($dados); retorna vários IDS, mas nenhum pedido

Comment: O estranho que ao por o todo texto contido dentro do arquivo id.txt em $data ='   '; ele retorna sem problemas, mas não faz o mesmo acesssando o arquivo.

Comment: Pode ser devido ao formato do final de linha do arquivo, atualizei as funções na resposta, realize um novo teste com todas elas.

Comment: Meu caro amigo HwapX, eu percebi agora o motivo dos erros, dentro do texto há, provavelmente caracteres especiais que estão prejudicando. Veja aqui o arquivo que desejo trabalhar: http://brasilro.com/id.txt

Comment: Realmente houveram problemas com as funções que utilizam expressão regular, porem obtive sucesso com as que não utilizam(buscarTexto2 e buscarTextos2).

Comment: Tudo resolvido! Muito Obrigado! Posso tê-lo como amigo?

Comment: @MarceloCordeiro Claro

Answer (score 0):

Para resolver este problema você pode utilizar expressões regulares.

Como você aparentemente já possui o `id` que deseja ler e é bastante óbvio o padrão que segue este arquivo de texto (se todo o conteúdo estiver formatado dessa forma). Logo você pode escrever uma expressão regular como esta:

`/[valor_do_id]\$\n(.*)\$/`

Um exemplo utilizando a função `preg_match` do `PHP` seria mais ou menos dessa forma:

```
  $conteudo_do_arquivo = '....';
  $id = 1000;

  $matches; // vai armazenar os resultados da regex.
  preg_match("/" . $id . "\$\n(.*)\$/", $conteudo_do_arquivo, $matches);

   // [0] vai conter toda a string compativel com o regex
   // [1] vai conter apenas o valor do 1º grupo de captura, tudo entre '()'.
  print_r($matches);
```

Você pode ler mais sobre a função preg_match no [php.net](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.preg-match.php)

Você também pode utilizar o [Regexr](https://regexr.com/) para testar suas expressões de antemão.

Comment: A maneira retorna no navegador apenas: Array ( ). 

Fiz algumas mudanças alterando o $ para #.

Ficando agora assim: #1000#
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt.#

1001#
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt.#